# Blood type compatibility GUI

Tags: java, beginner

I was asked to make a blood type compatibility GUI app. The code compiles and functions how I want it to. When a blood type is selected from the combo box a message box pops up with all the compatible types. I feel that there could be an easy way of doing this though. Could I please have any advice on how to improve on this?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.HashMap;



public class assigmentSeven extends Frame {
private JFrame container;
private JPanel mainPanel; 
private JLabel firstLabel;
private JComboBox<String> selectBloodType = new JComboBox<>();
public assigmentSeven () //constructor 
{
guione();
}
    public void guione() //method 
    {
        container = new JFrame("Blood compatibility  App");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        container.setVisible(true);
        container.setSize(300, 170);
        container.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        container.setResizable(true);
        container.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        firstLabel = new JLabel("Please select your blood type : ");
        firstLabel.setBounds(25, 60,250, 20);
        String[] bloodTypeArrayAppearance = {"O-","O+ ","A- ","A+ ","B- 
   ","B+ ", "AB- ","AB+ "};
        HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<>();
        hash.put("O-", "O-");
        hash.put("O+", "O+, O-");
        hash.put("A-", "O-, A-");
        hash.put("A+", "O-, O+, A-, A+");
        hash.put("B-", "O-, B- ");
        hash.put("B+", "O-, O+, B-, B+");
        hash.put("AB-", "O-, A-, B-, AB-");
        hash.put("AB+", "O-, O+, A-, A+, B-, B+, AB-, AB+");
        String oMinus = hash.get("O-");
        String oPlus = hash.get("O+");
        String aMinus = hash.get("A-");
        String aPlus = hash.get("A+");
        String bMinus = hash.get("B-");
        String bPlus = hash.get("B+");
        String abMinus = hash.get("AB-");
        String abPlus = hash.get("AB+");
        final JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

        JComboBox selectBloodType = new JComboBox(bloodTypeArrayAppearance);
                      selectBloodType.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
                          @Override 

        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() != ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                return;
            }
            Object item = selectBloodType.getSelectedItem();
            if (bloodTypeArrayAppearance[0].equals(item)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bloodTypeArrayAppearance[0] + " is compatibal with " + oMinus,
                        "Blood type", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            }
            else if(bloodTypeArrayAppearance[1].equals(item)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bloodTypeArrayAppearance[1] + " is compatibal with " + oPlus, 
                        "Blood type", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            }
            else if(bloodTypeArrayAppearance[2].equals(item)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bloodTypeArrayAppearance[2] + " is compatibal with " + aMinus,
                        "Blood type", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            }
            else if(bloodTypeArrayAppearance[3].equals(item)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bloodTypeArrayAppearance[3] + " is compatibal with " + aPlus,
                        "Blood type", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            }
            else if(bloodTypeArrayAppearance[4].equals(item)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bloodTypeArrayAppearance[4] + " is compatibal with " + bMinus,
                        "Blood type", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            }
            else if(bloodTypeArrayAppearance[5].equals(item)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bloodTypeArrayAppearance[5] + " is compatibal with " + bPlus,
                        "Blood type", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            }
            else if(bloodTypeArrayAppearance[6].equals(item)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bloodTypeArrayAppearance[6] + " is compatibal with " + abMinus,
                        "Blood type", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            }
            else if(bloodTypeArrayAppearance[7].equals(item)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bloodTypeArrayAppearance[7] + " is compatibal with " +abPlus,
                        "Blood type", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            }

                }
    });;

            mainPanel.add(selectBloodType);
mainPanel.add(firstLabel);
mainPanel.add(selectBloodType);
container.add(mainPanel);                     


}

                        public static void main(String [] args){
                             new assigmentSeven();
                            }
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/182089/revisions) to a different one that describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are some remarks about this code. The usual ones is about naming and code style conventions. (btw you have a type in `assigmentSeven`, missing `n`).

After that we have the good practices with the usual separation of concerns. You should start to move the resolution logic to a dedicated "class" so that you can easily (unit) test it. An then use it via your UI.

For a simple ux perspective, I cannot choose "O-" at the beginning because he is already selected.

## Cleanup

- Rename your class with a better name, or at least with CamelCase
- Remove all the useless things. You don't have to `extends JFrame` since you are building another one. Either rename or merge the `initone` method with your constructor. `private JPanel mainPanel` and `private JComboBox<String> selectBloodType` can be removed, you are building another one (with the same name !) in your initialization method.
- At the end, you are adding the `selectBloodType` twice to the `mainPanel` and the first add is useless.

## Avoid duplication

You are building a `String[]`, then a `Map<String, String>` then a couple of `String` with all the same information. And because of that you have to duplicate all your resolution logic into a suit of `if .. else if`.

The understanding of this logic is not easy because of the mental map that we have to keep between `bloodTypeArrayAppearance[..]` and the effective blood type.

All of that duplication can be replaced by 3 lines of code :

```
String selected = (String) e.getItem();
String compatibility = hash.get(selected );
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
        selected + " is compatible with " + compatibility ,
        "Blood type", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

I have renamed `item` to `selected` and added `compatibility` to have meaningful names. And also solved the `compatibal` typos with `compatible`

You can drop a lot of lines but loose the ordering of blood types : `"O-", "O+ ", "A- ", "A+ ", "B- ", "B + ", "AB - ", "AB + "` but that is solved by using another type of map : `HashMap<String, String> hash = new LinkedHashMap<>();`

## UI issue

I have some UI issues with your frame being empty and having to resize it to have the label and select box.This one can be solved by moving the `container.setVisible(true);` at the end of your initialization method, when your container is ready.

## Personal tips

I'm used to move things that never change as final fields. `container` and firstLabel` are good candidates for that :

```
private final JFrame container = new JFrame("Blood compatibility  App");
private final JLabel usage = new JLabel("Please select your blood type : ");
```

I also rename `firstLabel` to `usage` to have a more meaningfull name.

## Separation of concerns

The only thing that you still have to do is to extract the blood type resolution to a service.

```
class BloodService {
    private static HashMap<String, String> COMPATIBILITY = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    static {
        COMPATIBILITY.put("O-", "O-");
        COMPATIBILITY.put("O+", "O+, O-");
        COMPATIBILITY.put("A-", "O-, A-");
        COMPATIBILITY.put("A+", "O-, O+, A-, A+");
        COMPATIBILITY.put("B-", "O-, B- ");
        COMPATIBILITY.put("B+", "O-, O+, B-, B+");
        COMPATIBILITY.put("AB-", "O-, A-, B-, AB-");
        COMPATIBILITY.put("AB+", "O-, O+, A-, A+, B-, B+, AB-, AB+");
    }

    public List<String> getAllTypes() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(COMPATIBILITY.keySet()));
    }

    public String getCompatibility(String type) {
        return COMPATIBILITY.get(type);
    }
}
```

Now you can easily test your resolution via a unit tests. And the UI is cleanly unaware of any business logic. It just have to expect an instance of `BloodService` via his constructor.

## Food for tought

- To create efficient Swing ui there are some things to know. One good thing is to document yourself on the *EDT* and use `SwingUtilities`.
- You can thing to a better and more typed system to resolve the compatibility. (`enum` ?)
- I'm far to be and UI expert but the users don't like to have popups. Try to show the result in the frame instead of another one. And try to solve the bug about the initial selection of *"O-"*.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, we are strictly adhere to start class names with a capital letter.

```
assigmentSeven -> AssigmentSeven
```

In Java Swing applications, it is a good practice to follow that inside the constrcutor we only initialize the components*(UI elements)* with default values.

Use **Single resposibility** for any method you write. 
`guione` is not a meaningful name. *(It doesn't interpret what the method is supposed to do)* `initialize()` would be a good alternative.

move your `main` method at the top of the class to quick visibility.

Move the hashmap initialization to a different method. Kind of a helper method.